# How to place taxonomy menu block into a content?

Tags: drupal-7

I've a taxonomy menu block. I want to show it in a Node/content. I googling and tried

http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/placing-a-drupal-block-inside-a-node/

but not working for me. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain the "Not working" status? Mean there is no block shown or there is an error?

If you have access to the **php code text format** (admin/config/content/formats) you can put the block using php code. See example here:

https://snipt.net/ivan747/add-block-to-node/

Comment: Yes. I do not see any block at there.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? Did you follow the instructions of installing the insert_block module?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) you can create a Block Field and display it anywhere in your content as a field.

Take a look at this screencast by Kristof De Jaeger:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvFP16PJt4c